# Alternative to set focus from within the Enter event

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a textbox and in some cases in Enter event I need to set the focus to a different textbox.

I tried that code:

```
 private void TextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(_skipTextBox1) TextBox2.Focus();
 }
```

But this code doesn't work. After that I found on MSDN:

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers.

So how can I do it other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postpone executing the Focus() method until after the event is finished executing.  Elegantly done by using the Control.BeginInvoke() method.  Like this:

```
    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox3.Focus(); });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event instead:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
   {
      e.Handled = true;
      TextBox2.Focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not 'Enter key' but 'Enter event'. <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx">Control.Enter</a>

Comment: @Alex - Ah ok sorry.  In that case I would probably setup a `Timer` and just enable it on the Enter event and set the `Interval` for something small like 200ms or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox.Select();
```

or

```
textBox.Focus();
```

or
`set TabIndex = 0` from properties of that `textBox`.

both methods are use to set focus on `textBox` in **C#**, **.NET**