# WinForms firing Enter event twice

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got the following:

```
private void fooForm_Enter( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
     FooBar()
}

private void FooBar()
{
     Console.Out.WriteLine( "Foo" );
     /*
     do stuff
     */
     OtherControl.Focus();
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing here is that I get to see the text in the console twice, even though I only put focus on the fooForm once. However, if I comment out the OtherControl.focus() line, FooBar will only be called once. (No, OtherControl is not the same object as fooForm.)

What causes this and what can I do to make sure FooBar is only called once?

Comment: Changing the focus in a focusing event is never a great idea.   Also pretty important to focus a bit on how the form could possibly get the focus when it has OtherControl.  You need to post real code that can repro this issue to get help, this isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more googling and found a good solution to achieve the functionality I wanted without setting the focus in those events as per the solution here: [Alternative to set focus from within the Enter event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539074/alternative-to-set-focus-from-within-the-enter-event)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding.

You appear to be doing just that.

Comment: I see, I didn't see that. What can I do then to achieve this functionality? Because I want to perform something when one form gets the focus and then set the focus to another control. What would be the good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Enter and Leave events are hierarchical and will cascade up and down the parent chain until the appropriate control is reached.

Thus, your `fooForm` receives `Enter` event for its children too.

Also notice, from the same MSDN article:

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding.